# Level managing in games

Tags: libgdx, game-engine

What is best way to handle with lots of levels? Should i have some specified table which contains info about every level or should i write code for each level? For examle games like "Angry Birds", "Cut the rope", etc. have lots of levels, how they handle with them? And is there some specific way to solve my problem in libgdx? Maybe there exist some tool to pack all information about levels. What do you recommend?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for Angry Birds or Cut the Rope, as I am simply creating a libGDX/box2d game as a hobby. But I would imagine using your own level editor or some editor that is available is preferred. Hand coding each level inside your game seems like a giant pain.

Use the editor to create/tweak the levels, save them in some format and read them in as needed in your game. Makes extending the game easier too.

I personally use R.U.B.E. It saves the levels as json, and my game serializes them as needed. I imagine you could add encryption/something to the levels so they're not easily accessible for snooping. RUBE is not free, but I'd suggest looking around, or write your own. If you're going to create lots of levels, you'll need a level editor.